# How to Display the list of wordpress categories with their ids

Tags: wordpress, list, parent-child, categories

Can anyone please tell me how to display my wordpress categories (parents and childs) along with their ids.
i want them printed in this way:

Europe,United Kingdom,London  (Europe is a parent category and their childs united kingdom)
10,20,33  (these are their ids)

Europe,France,Paris
10,22,45

Europe,France,Cannes
10,22,49

I tried this code but it didn't work for me:

```
     <?php  
$categories = get_the_category();
 $this_cat_ID = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
 $this_cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name;
 $this_cat_url = get_category_link($this_cat_ID);
 // get the sub category if we have them
 foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $parent = $cat->category_parent;
    if ($parent != 0 ){
       $sub_cat_ID = $cat->cat_ID;
       $sub_cat_name = $cat->cat_name;
       $sub_cat_url = get_category_link($sub_cat_ID);
    }
 }
 if (!$sub_cat_ID) {
   echo $this_cat_ID;
} else {
   echo $sub_cat_ID;
}
?>
```

Your help is very much appreciated thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Please read the **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)** on how to ask a question.

Comment: Do you want all your categories or just the categories related to a particular post.

Comment: Peter, i want the ids of all my categories and their childs and the childs of the childs. thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the version on your site.

Comment: Yeah it works, just awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordPress function [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) will return a list of all the categories.  If you set the hierarchical flag to true you will get the whole hierarchy.  Read the codex article in the link above for details.

There is also a [get_categories function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)  that returns an unformatted result.  You could use this in your own PHP code.

A third choice is to read the database, there are three tables wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_term_relationships that contain the category tree.  Here's [the database structure](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

Edit: Here's a shortcode that will produce a listing like that as a nested collection of lists:

```
function show_categories($atts, $content) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array('taxonomy' => 'category'), $atts ) );
    $cats = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy,'hide_empty' => 0, 'hierarchical' => 0, 'parent' => 0));
    return show_categories_level($cats, '', '', $taxonomy);
}

function show_categories_level($cats, $names, $ids,$taxonomy) {
    $res = '<ul>';
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        if($names)$n = "$names, $cat->name"; else $n = $cat->name;
        if($ids)$i = "$ids, $cat->term_id"; else $i = $cat->term_id;    
        $res = $res."<li>$n : $i</li>";
        $kittens = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy,'hide_empty' => 0, 'hierarchical' => 0, 'parent' =>$cat->term_id));
        if($kittens) {
            $res .= ("<li>".show_categories_level($kittens, $n, $i, $taxonomy)."</li>");
        }
    }
    return $res."</ul>";
}
add_shortcode('show-categories', 'show_categories');
```

To use this add this code to your functions.php and add the shortcode wherever you want it to display:

```
<h2>Default Categories</h2>
[show-categories]
```

or you can specify a taxonomy that you want listed

```
<h2>My Taxonomy Categories</h2>
[show-categories taxonomy="my_taxonomy"]
```

This isn't the most efficient way to get this result, but it works here.  If you started with the hierarchical version of get_categories or used the database you could get a faster version of this.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your fast reply, can you please tell me the code because i'm not good at php.

Comment: I'm afraid sir, i really appreciate your kindness and attempts to help me but the code doesn't work for me. Actually i added the first code to functions.php and the shortcode to catlist.php. However all i can see is: **Shopp Categories
[show-categories taxonomy="shopp_category"]
Default Categories
[show-categories]**

Comment: if you are seeing [] on the page it means that shortcodes are not working.  Can you check if the code to install them (the add_shortcode) actually ran?

Comment: The shortcode only works on posts and pages.  to use it in php code you need to use the do_shortcode function.

Comment: Peter your code works flawlessly. Well done Peter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to display this? inside loop? outside? in single.php? category.php? .....?

If you want to display it in a separate place, include first wp-load.php, like this

```
<? php


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset: UTF-8');
require( '../../../../wp-load.php' ); // use the path which will fit your situation

$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query(array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'orderby'   => 'title',
          'order'     => 'ASC',
        ));

if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

// use your code here after checking codex

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: if you still dont know how to use this, I promise tomorrow to give full code source. but i advice to digg into it to learn. Wordpress is a big useful world. a+

Comment: So kind of you letter and blank spaces, i'm not very good at php, if you can give full code to help me out i will be grateful to you.

Comment: where are you in this? you didn't answer my question! Where do you want to display this? inside loop? outside? in single.php? category.php? .....? in a separate custom place?

Answer (score 0):

What i want to do is this:
[The steps I Followed](http://www.ehow.com/how_8381770_export-list-categories-wordpress.html) (please check this link)

I only want to change this code:

```
<ul> <?php wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li=&hide_empty=0'); ?></ul>
```

so that the list of of all the categories and their childs will be displayed along with their ids in this format:

Example:
**Europe,United Kingdom,London, East Ham :   25,28,34,36**
this is just one parent category (Europe) and its childs (Uk)
the child of UK is London, and the child of london is East Ham.
25 is the id of Europe, 28 is the id of UK, 34 is the id of London, 36 is the id of East Ham

Please note: I just want to display this list on a page as described in the link above.
Thank you so much

Comment: I've added some code to my answer that produces a list like you are asking for.